# how to delete a folder which is empty using PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php 
function rmdirr($dirname){
    // Sanity check
    $dirname = "TEST/";
    if (!file_exists($dirname)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Simple delete for a file
    if (is_file($dirname)) {
        return unlink($dirname);
    }

    // Loop through the folder
    $dir = dir($dirname);
    while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
        // Skip pointers
        if ($entry == "." || $entry == "..") {
            continue;
        }

        // Recurse
        unlink("$dirname/$entry");
    }

    // Clean up
    $dir->close();
    return rmdir($dirname);
}
if (rmdirr($_GET['map'])){
    echo "TEST FERo";
}
else{
    echo "something went wrong.";
}
?>
```

Its working well and good. But if i need to delete the folder which contains some files and empty folder. In this case it delete all the files but not the empty folder. It throws an exception like…

```
Warning: unlink(TEST//New Folder) [function.unlink]: Permission denied 
  in E:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\delete_FILE\delete_FILE.php on line 23

Warning: rmdir(TEST/) [function.rmdir]: Directory not empty in
  E:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\delete_FILE\delete_FILE.php on line 28
```

What is the possible way to delete even the folder is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Just use your rmdirr function recursively in the while loop instead of unlink;

```
function rmdirr($dirname){ 
  // Sanity check 
  if (!file_exists($dirname)) { return false; }

  // Simple delete for a file 
  if (is_file($dirname)) { return unlink($dirname); }

  // Loop through the folder 
  $dir = dir($dirname); 
  while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) { 
    // Skip pointers 
    if ($entry == "." || $entry == "..") { continue; }

    // Recurse
    rmdirr("$dirname/$entry"); 

  }

  // Clean up 
  $dir->close(); 
  return rmdir($dirname); 
}
```

This way it'll also take care of non-empty subfolders...

Comment: Keep in mind that the `$dirname = "TEST/";` line at the top prevents the function from being used recursively.

Comment: i tried your code its not working as per my specifications. The following error is occurring when i used it. Fatal error: Call to undefined function rmdirr() in E:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\delete_FILE\delete_FILE.php on line 26

Answer (score 1):

you have to make sure your webserver is able to delete those files. check the permissions.

Comment: i am working in my local machine. Kindly advice me How to check your Criteria?

Comment: your would have to check the security tab of the property of concerned folders

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the files in 1 level only. Your code tries to delete the folder  `TEST//New Folder` using `unlink` instead of `rmdir`. You have to check if it's a folder or not, then `rmdir` or `unlink` it.

Comment: check kkyy's answer .. he fixed it :)

Comment: i tried kkyy's code its not working as per my specifications. The following error is occurring when i used it.

Fatal error: Call to undefined function rmdirr() in E:\Xampp\xampp\htdocs\delete_FILE\delete_FILE.php on line 26

Comment: make sure the function name is `rmdirr`. If you changed that, you need to change it also in the line where it says `//Recurse`.